# How to format URL from wordpress media folder to work with BabylonJS

Tags: wordpress, url, babylonjs

I have a 3d interactive element in a site I am building, and I need it to reference a GLTF file that I will be uploading to the Wordpress media folder. I can get it to work with this url from github: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/master/2.0/Duck/glTF-Binary/Duck.glb
but I cannot get it to work with any of the files I am uploading. I assume I need to change the syntax of the WP file url, but nothing I have tried has worked. Is there a change I can make to the syntax of the url that will make it work, or will I need to host the GLTF somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Babylon loads assets the same way you load images in wordpress.

What could be a problem is maybe wordpress doesn't allow uploading .glb files, or your web server might not have the correct mimetype set for hosting .glb files.

I would suggest trying to upload a glb, and check that mimetype is correctly set, and that you can download it as usual from the wp-content/uploads folder.

Then you should be able to pass in the full url to the gltf loader as usual.

Comment: I know WordPress will allow you to upload glbs, I can't speak to the mimetype, that's something I would need to read up on. I did find some very specific guidelines for url formatting on the Babylon site, it unfortunately didn't mention anything about wordpress though. I hosted the file in dropbox and linked to it from there as a workaround, which is working well but long term it would be nice to have a way to do this directly from WP.